# Possible to convert from integer to decimal?

Tags: java, mysql

I've run into a bit of a problem when trying to get a decimal result from a query. Initially, I had two int columns, and my goal was to return a decimal value. However, from what I've been told, a decimal can only be returned if both columns are float and if the method in Java also is a float, otherwise it would either round the result or (if Java returned a float) return the result in a zero after the decimal.

In short, is it true that the only way to get a true decimal value is by using two float columns rather than int?

Comment: Why two columns to store a single value?

Comment: Use `DECIMAL` type for the column in your database.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. If you have two int columns and e.g. you return the result of dividing one value by the other, the result can be a decimal value if proper care is taken not to round back into an int.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, this is tagged java but smells more like SQL ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, its not at all true
you can check like ::

```
ResultSet rs =  // resultset after a query execution 
if(rs.next())
{

double v1 = (Double)rs.getDouble(1);
int v2  = (Integer)rs.getInt(2);
}
```

This snippet runs fine..